# ASP.net download file Using HttpContext.Current.Response fileName

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, httpresponse, html-encode

I am trying to download a file using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response using the following code:

```
HttpResponse objResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
```

I am encoding the file name using:

```
FileName = Uri.EscapeDataString(FileName);
```

The file is downloading correctly, except when I have comma or dot in the file name.

In that case, while downloading the file, the explorer cannot decode the comma back.

For instance:

```
Original file name: Testing, File
Encoded name: Testing%2C%20file
Downloaded file name:  Testing%2C file
```

Is there any way to code/encode the file name, in order to keep the commas and dots?

Comment: Why are you encoding the file name? It is not an URI.

Answer (score 0):

for example, you can use:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFileXML(string filePath)
{
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
return File(filePath, "application/xml", fileName);
}
```